# Open file in external application from netrw?

Tags: vim

Is there any way to configure netrw so it could open files in external applications based on file extension. For example if I have a directory with pictures can I select them in netrw and open them in an external image viewer (the system default for example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, in the netrw directory listing, you can trigger this by pressing `x` (and even in arbitrary text buffer via `gx`); cp. [`:help netrw-x`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/pi_netrw.txt.html#netrw-x).

By default, this will delegate the external opening of the file to your operating system's default file handler; these typically examine the filename's extension and do the "right thing". You can change the default external handler, or even customize this functionality with a Vimscript function; cp. [`:help netrw_filehandler`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/pi_netrw.txt.html#netrw_filehandler).